# How do I replace current fragment after clicking a Gridview inside in tabhost of another Fragment?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have this problem. I have a Fragment with a ViewFlipper and a TabHost with inside three tabs and in the first tab I have a Gridview with Items. I want to replace the current fragment with another by clicking an item of the gridView.
The relevant sample code that I  written:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.princ_fragment_2, container,
            false);


    //mTabHost = rootView.getTabHost();
    mTabHost = (TabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Turnario").setContent(R.id.gridView));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("CarSharing").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Altro").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


    mContext = this.getActivity();
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
    mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

    **gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.row_grid, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {


        ***public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(),null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v(TAG,"GRIDVIEW ITEM TOUCH");
            }
        });***
    return rootView;
}**
```

I debugging this piece of code, but the event  onItemClick() is not execute.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

if (position == Constants.GRID_POSITION_ZERO) {

```
                FragmentHelper fragmentHelper = FragmentHelper.getInstance();

                fragmentHelper.replaceFragment(R.id.fragment_holder, new LiveEventFragment(), ((HomeActivity) getActivity()), "Live_Event");
       }
```

fragment helper is  a class where u can mange all fragment operations